# Chrome text render bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, text-rendering

Examples of text glitch :

[image]

[image]

If hover on element the glitch is fade out.

I tried all value of `-webkit-font-smoothing` and `text-rendering` stop on this one

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
```

better but don't fix the problem.

font importing like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local(''),
  url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-900.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-900.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-900.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-900.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
  url('../fonts/inter-v12-latin-900.svg#Inter') format('svg');
}
```

hardware acceleration make it better but don't fix it too

Comment: Problem was solved. On windows when you use `transform: translateZ(0);` и `backface-visibility: hidden;` text rendering is broke

Comment: Add your solution inside an answer ;)